# Why have my Chrome windows metastasized?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Chrome was fine when I shut it down last night, but when I opened it up today, the entire window had gone huge. I know I can make the web content zoom in and out easily enough, but the tabs, the address bar, bookmarks bar, etc., were also all much bigger than normal.

Across the rest of my computer, there haven't been any changes to resolution or anything else that I can think of to explain this. Desktop icons are the same size, Office applications look normal, Firefox, everything.

My understanding is that these settings are supposed to be somehow linked to the Windows settings, but moving those up and down didn't do anything for me either. Any idea how to get this thing back to normal size?

**EDIT: Screenshots included**

Used to look like this:
[image: Screen1]

Now looks like this:
[image]

Comment: First step; Backup the profile then delete it.  See if that solves the problem.  A screenshot would also be very helpful.  I have never heard of "metasized" in 25 years working with a computer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing screenshots, but I don't have enough reputation points yet. FWIW: 'metastasized' is a piece of medical jargon that I heard and always think of whenever anything gets too big.

I'll give the backup and delete a try.

Comment: Clearing the profile didn't work, but I have added screenshots. Also worth noting: the problem doesn't occur when I'm signed in to Chrome on other computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Navigate to the Chrome.exe(Usually in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application).
2) Right click -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check Disable display scaling on high DPI settings.

I am not sure what is causing the problem in your computer, but this is usually caused in laptops with small screen size and high resolution (High DPI, for e.g. Surface pro).

EDIT:

1) Right click on desktop -> Select screen resolution -> click on make text and other items larger or smaller and then try moving the bar and see if it solves the problem.

or

2) Open device manager right click on the display driver and click on properties -> select driver -> check for updates(maybe the outdated driver is causing the issue) -> or -> rollback driver(maybe the updated driver caused the issue)

or

3) Uninstall and re-install chrome as the last resort(maybe the installation got corrupted).

If it still doesn't work, you have found a bug.

Go here : "https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en" to write a bug report.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I don't get an option to disable display scaling. I've got a dropdown for compatibility mode, then Display setting (256 colors, 640X680 resolution, disable visual themes), and then an option to turn off advanced text services.

Comment: Hhmm... Interesting. I am getting the option in for chrome in all my laptops. I am sensing it is a graphic card driver issue. I want you to try one more thing : Right click on desktop -> Select screen resolution -> click on make text and other items larger or smaller and then try moving the bar and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: If that doesn't help, open device manager right click on the display driver and click on properties -> select driver -> check for updates(maybe the outdated driver is causing the issue) -> or -> rollback driver(maybe the updated driver caused the issue) -> or -> uninstall and re-install chrome as the last resort(maybe the installation got corrupted).

Comment: Resolution didn't fix anything, and the drivers all say they're up to date and don't have any previous versions backed up. Guess I'll give the re-install a shot.

Comment: Re-install worked. IF you want to edit your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I have also kept all the possible answers for others to try out should they have similar issue. You can now mark as accepted. :)